# How to fix a Laravel Sail "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'XXX.XXX.X.X' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" error

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-9, laravel-sail

**Laravel:** 9.2
**Mac OS:** 12.3.1
**Docker Desktop:** 4.5.0

I have installed a default Laravel project using sail. My docker-compose.yml file includes the following:

```
mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
```

And my default environment variables are:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=example_2012
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

But when I try to connect to the database from sail artisan and http://localhost. I receive the following error:

```
Host 'XXX.XXX.X.X' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

"docker ps -a | grep mysql" returns:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX   mysql/mysql-server:8.0        "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)      33060-33061/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp                example-2022_mysql_1
```

I've tried amending the ports to 3307 but without success.

Comment: have you try to add `FORWARD_DB_PORT` pointing to different port in your .env file?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue with a MariaDB container. While searching for a solution I came across [this Github answer](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/issues/18#issuecomment-539847213). Long story short:

```
docker-compose down -v
docker volume prune
docker container prune
sail up
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your output it should be port 3308 which is forwarded to 3306 in the container